# LiveReload for Sublime Text 2 & Firefox

Tags: firefox, laravel, localhost, sublimetext2, livereload

I am using Win7 64bit. I just tried to install LiveReload into Sublime Text together with the addon for Firefox. However, when I try to run it, it says "Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that a compatible LiveReload server is running. (We recommand guard-livereload, until LiveReload 2 comes to your platform.)"

Why is it cannot run? Is there anything else I need to install? Does LiveReload works with localhost and Laravel?

Thanks.

Comment: About "Install LiveReload into Sublime Text". How did  you do that? What Sublime Text package? Also, what version of sublime do you use?

Comment: I think it still not compatible with Windows yet.

Comment: I install LiveReload with Package Control. This is the version I am using: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LiveReload

About the browser extension, I get it from here: http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the reason it is not working is because of my Kaspersky Internet Security blocking it. In order to get it works, I have to disable "Web antivirus" and "safe money" function in Kaspersky Internet Security.

If you know any other work around way, such as instead of disable the function but adding exclusion and etc, please share with me. It will be really great if can get it works without disabling the function.